# How to display a file path in an editable text box in MATLAB GUI if user has entered text or cleared the text box

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm developing a GUI using Guide. I've created a file browse button to select a directory. Once the directory is selected, the path is displayed in an editable text box. My problem is that when the text box is cleared by the user, the browse button is pushed again, and a new directory is selected, nothing is displayed in the text box. If the user enters any text into the box and the browse button is pushed, MATLAB returns the following error: Error using set, Value must be a handle.
How do I get it so that if the user clears or enters text into the text box, the file browse button can still be used?

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
indir = uigetdir;
if indir ~= 0
    set(handles.edit1, 'String', indir);
end
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Comment: Can you simply change the edit box to a regular text box that the user can't modify? Maybe a missed something but that would avoid possible errors.

Comment: That is an option I considered, but I was hoping to give the user an option to manually enter or change the path, and still be able to use the browse button afterwards. However, I may just have to do this.